# UITableView reloadData doesn't work?

Tags: uitableview

I tried to write a test demo for an IM app,so I designed a simple UI to chat with other buddy:while I send a message out I will reload the UITableView to show the message as the same as i receive a message.
The problem is,when I send out the message,the UITableView will refresh after I call the reloadData method,but when I receive a message it doesn't work at all,I have to pull down or up the UITableView then it will refresh.
I did set the dataSource and UITableView delegate,and I did connect the IBOutlet property with the nib file,I did check the IBOutlet property's value before I call the reloadData(it contained a valid value),and I did check the dataSource's value(when I received a message it's value changed and one message was inserted into it).
So please tell me what wrong with it after all?

Comment: Are you sure you are calling `reloadData` on the main thread? All UI actions should be called from the main thread otherwise unexpected things will happen.

Comment: Thank you very much.I caught the reason as you explained and I found that the receive message method is called by a child thread and.So change the my source code as:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you @Tim very much.I caught the reason as you explained and I found that the receive message method is called by a child thread and.So change the my source code as :

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [self.tv_chat_records reloadData];
    });
```

it works!

Comment: Be careful with the use of `self` in blocks. This can lead to retain cycles and thus memory leaks. It is generally better to use a weak self pattern when using asynchronous blocks.